# Ошибка при совершении транзакции

Tags: jpa, java, tomcat, ejb

Здравствуйте. Я использую Tomcat OpenEJB. При вызове метода **`em.persist(myObj);`**, вылетает такая ошибка:

> javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction was rolled back, presumably because setRollbackOnly was called during a synchronization 
> at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.convertException (BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:341)
> ...
>
> Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: Unable to commit: transaction marked for rollback at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl.commit (TransactionImpl.java:271)
> ...

Может у кого есть идеи, как мне помочь?
Мой класс выглядит примерно так:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "todolistUnit", type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
private EntityManager em;
public void addTask(String task, Timestamp endDate, Integer categoryId) {
    TlTasks tasks = new TlTasks();
    tasks.setTask(task);
    tasks.setEndTime(endDate);
    tasks.setCategoryId(categoryId);
    em.persist(tasks);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка была в классе сущности, объявляющего таблицу

```
@javax.persistence.Table(name = "TL_Tasks", schema = "dbo", catalog = "todoListDB")
@Entity
public class TlTasks {
private int id;

@javax.persistence.Column(name = "id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false, length = 10, precision = 0)
@Id
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
```

В объявлениях свойств индексного столбца
**insertable = false, updatable = false** стояло **true**. Вот на этом этапе и вылетала ошибка.